# Cant get public boolean removeBorrower(String libraryNumber) to work

Tags: java, arraylist, static, indexing, boolean

The code needs to be able to reference two library numbers together, and if they are equal, remove the borrower from the array.
It won't let me run a method from another class because it's a static context. I don't know how else to solve this. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
public boolean removeBorrower(String libraryNumber)
{ 
    if(libraryNumber == null)
        return false;
    else if(Borrower.getLibraryNumber().equals(libraryNumber)))
        borrowers.remove(Borrower);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a more precise SSCCE?

Comment: What do you mean that it won't let you?  I don't see a Borrower class or a variable named Borrower (which would be bad naming convention, but legal), or an error message from the compiler.  In fact, there's not even enough code here to compile.  Please provide a complete working example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a reference to the other `Borrower` you want to compare against:

```
public boolean removeBorrower(String libraryNumber, Borrower otherBorrower)
{ 
    if(libraryNumber == null)
        return false;
    else if(otherBorrower.getLibraryNumber().equals(libraryNumber)))
        borrowers.remove(otherBorrower);
    return true;
}
```

Before, you were trying the get the library number for the generic `Borrower` class, which doesn't make conceptual sense. With this code, you have a specific person to check the library number of.

Comment: Fixed a bug I had with `remove()` just now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get an instance of the class containing `removeBorrower` method.

I don't think that you can't run the method from another class (unless the method is contained in a package-private class and the client class is not part of the same package).

Maybe you wanted to say that you're not allowed to run this method without having a reference to an existing instance of the class containing `removeBorrwer` method.